# deluge has slower speed than transmission

Tags: networking, transmission, deluge, torrent-client

I am wondering why does transmission has higher download speed than deluge on the same torrent files? As of right now, transmission downloads 4 torrent files at about 7 MB/s, while deluge downloads exactly the same files at 2 MB/s (running both programs separately).

I tried changing up/down limits on deluge, deleting .config folder, accessing random ports on start, turning UDP option off and on, etc...

Also, I tried using qbittorrent and it has the same results as deluge.

OS = Ubuntu 16.04

P.S. the reason I am trying to get higher speed on diluge is because transmission down speed drops to 0 after some time (which is another issue)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm. Back when I torrented in the old days, Deluge was not noticeably slower than any other torrent client. Please edit your question to elaborate on why you think this is typical behavior that most folks experience?

Comment: @user535733 i dont know if its typical or not. I rather assume this is not typical. i wonder if there's a difference in settings that causes the speed difference